# How to repeat a function a certain number of times while collecting progressive outputs?

Tags: function, haskell, pattern-matching, mapping, repeat

I've looked at similar questions and have not found the solution to my specific question. I have a list of strings where I am using my own map function to map it to another function. This is an example function with no descript function names:

`functionName :: [String] -> [String]`

`functionName [] = []`

`functionName(x:xs) = otherFunction x : functionName xs`

I need to be able to repeat this function 25 times and a way that was suggested to me is to take the list [1..25] and then map my function to that list using a version of (x:xs). Is this possible? I was thinking it could be something like:

`thirdFunction :: [Int] -> [String] -> [String]`

`thirdFunction(x:xs) (y:ys) = ?? functionName : ?? thirdFunction`

I do not know what I would put in the line above but something to that effect with x:xs and y:ys to have two parameters instead of one. I only just started using Haskell about 5 days ago so I only know a limited amount of what is possible with it and having proper syntax.

Edit:
I need 25 different sets of output based on the previous one. So I am taking my list of strings, then changing each one through the functions (Let's call that output1). Then I'm taking output1 and changing it again through the same function process to then make output2

Comment: Check out [`iterate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate).

Comment: look at [`!!`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-) in addition to `iterate` - or try to implement `doTimes :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a` (use recursion)

Comment: Do you want a list of 25 separate results, or do you want to apply the function to its own output 25 times, or something else?

Comment: @chepner That is actually something I forgot to mention, I need 25 different sets of output based on the previous one. So I am taking my list of strings, then changing each one through the functions and that is output one. Then I'm taking that output and changing it again through the same function process but I need a separate output.

Comment: That might be (or at least,  use) `scanr`, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe in your edit is done with `iterate . map`:

```
> :t \f -> iterate (map f)
\f -> iterate (map f) :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [[a]]

> take 3 $ iterate (map (10 +)) [1..3]
[[1,2,3],[11,12,13],[21,22,23]]

> take 3 . drop 1 $ iterate (map (10+)) [1..3]
[[11,12,13],[21,22,23],[31,32,33]]
```

`iterate` goes on forever, so you need to `take` a certain number of the results from its output, in your case `take 25`. If you're not interested in the original input, you can skip over it with `drop 1`.

Comment: May I ask why you used `drop 1` instead of `tail`? Is it stylistic or because of differences in performance/semantics?

Comment: @Will Ness, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: @user here it makes absolutely no difference, and I even initially used `tail` myself, **but** -- `tail` errors out sometimes (is "partial", in Haskell jargon) while `drop 1` never errors out. so it's a good habit to have, to _never_ use `tail` and always use `drop 1` instead. one less thing to worry about. :)

Comment: @RobertPerrone you're welcome. :) you can "accept" the answer to signal the issue is resolved. :) also, to get better answers quicker always be specific and concrete. give specific examples, and their desired and actual behavior. cheers, :)